# Keycloak Admin CLI: setting Client Attributes

Tags: keycloak

I'd like to use keycloak CLI ( kcadm.sh ) to generate a set of clients which have some attributes (taken from the Web Interface) such as:

- Access type=confidential
- Direct Access Grant Enabled=On

Is there a reference for all attributes that can be passed to the Admin CLI? In the examples I can only see some
basic attributes.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easiest to set attributes by using the -s in your command. Like this

```
kcadm.sh create clients -r oidcrealm -s "clientId=testClient" -s "directAccessGrantsEnabled=true" -s "publicClient=false"
```

As for reference, the REST API docs a mentioned in the previous answere is good, but another tip is to set you desiered configuration in the keycloak GUI the export the configuration like this.

```
kcadm.sh get clients -r oidcrealm
```

All attributes will then be listed with the current values.

kcadm.sh also accepts JSON as input so if you have alot of attributes it is probably easier to run like this and gives a better overview later

```
kcadm.sh create clients -r oidcrealm -f - << EOF
{
  "clientId" : "oidc-client",
  "redirectUris": ["http://react:3000"],
  "standardFlowEnabled": true,
  "publicClient": true,
  "attributes": {
    "pkce.code.challenge.method":"S256"
  }
}
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [REST API docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/6.0/rest-api/index.html#_clients_resource) as reference.

Note [that](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#using-the-admin-cli):

> The Admin CLI works by making HTTP requests to Admin REST endpoints.
>   Access to them is protected and requires authentication.
>
> Consult the Admin REST API documentation for details about JSON
>   attributes for specific endpoints.